# Calling Function inside function Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, function, swift

I want to call the function textFieldShouldReturn inside the editText, but I don't know how, what should I do? I tried copying the hole function inside my editText function but it didn't work. 
The editText function recognize what button is being clicked and supposedly change the label of the button clicked for the label defined in the textFieldShouldReturn, but it is not working.

ViewController with edit

```
     import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldInput: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var iphoneSaveCharName: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charOne: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charTwo: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charThree: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var charFour: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    var savedText: String!
    var tempbutton: UIButton!

//    func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool {
//        savedText = textFieldInput.text
//        textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
//        return false
//    }



    @IBAction func editText(sender: AnyObject) {
        if sender is UILongPressGestureRecognizer &&
            sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

                textFieldInput.hidden = false


                var tempbutton = sender.view as UIButton

                textFieldEditCompleted(textFieldInput)


                if tempbutton.tag == 1 {
                    charOne.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if tempbutton.tag == 2{
                    charTwo.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if tempbutton.tag == 3{
                    charThree.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                } else if tempbutton.tag == 4{
                    charFour.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
                }
        }
    }

    func textFieldEditCompleted(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        savedText = textFieldInput.text
        textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
        tempbutton.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)
        return false
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        return textFieldEditCompleted(textFieldInput);
    }

}
```

Update 2: [Behavior](http://youtu.be/huO4CbHGhfc)

Comment: the textFieldShouldReturn method is handled by the UITextFieldDelegate, you shouldn't call it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you call that function ?

Also calling delegate methods is not a good practice and you should not do that.

Instead of that write a function like:

```
func textFieldEditCompleted(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    savedText = textFieldInput.text
    textFieldInput.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textFieldInput: UITextField) -> Bool
{
    return textFieldEditCompleted(textFieldInput);
}
```

You can call the `textFieldEditCompleted` function from `textFieldShouldReturn` and `editText`.

Comment: I added your code, but I still can't call the textFieldShouldReturn function in the editText.

Comment: @Skal: In your `editText` call `textFieldEditCompleted` not `textFieldShouldReturn`

Comment: I was able to put the textFieldEditCompleted inside the editText function, but it not changed the behavior the way I expected. I updated the question with a youtube video of what is going on

Comment: @Skal: What was your expected output ?

Comment: You long press the button, it will show the text field them you input your text, press Done and the input you gave will change the button label

Comment: @Skal: You can't implement it like this way. You need to create a temporary button as global instance. In your edit button assign tempButton = sender.view; And in `textFieldEditCompleted` write like `tempButton.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you said

Comment: `let button` it as an instance variable.

Comment: I edited my post with the new code, it is giving me the fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when I set the `tempbutton` to be a global instance

Comment: @Skal: Check with `tempbutton?.setTitle(savedText, forState: .Normal)`

Comment: It is working now, but still not changed the behavior and keyboard not appearing anymore

Comment: @Skal: You are still using local variable tempButton instead of global one `var tempbutton = sender.view as UIButton`

Comment: But I can't call the sender.view outside the ediText